# Unable to install nforce in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, salesforce, apex

I wrote following function in AWS Lambda

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); //aws-sdk is node.js sdk for AWS
var nforce = require('nforce'); //nforce is node.js REST API Wrapper for Salesforce

//Make connection to connected App - Start 
var org = nforce.createConnection({
  clientId: 'Client_ID',
  clientSecret: 'CLIENT_SECRENT',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/_callback',
  apiVersion: 'v45.0',  // optional, defaults to current salesforce API version
  environment: 'production',  // optional, salesforce 'sandbox' or 'production', production default
  mode: 'single' // optional, 'single' or 'multi' user mode, multi default
});
//Make Connection to connected App - End

// Authenticate single-user mode - Start
org.authenticate({ username: 'USER_NAME', password: 'PASSWORD'}, function(err, resp){
  // the oauth object was stored in the connection object
  if(!err) {
      console.log('Cached Token: ' + org.oauth.access_token);
  }else{
       console.log("Error authenticating to Salesforce, " + err);
  }
});
//Authenticate single-user mode - End
```

The above code fails at line #2 with following error

```
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'nforce'",
```

Comment: Have you followed the packaging guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html ? You need to upload your function with `nforce` module in node_modules directory.

Comment: @Yann: Thanks for response, my folder structure is not correct, I corrected the directory structure, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can also upload the nforce module as a layer, and then your code above would also work.